# confused with K&R's 1.5.4 example

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

there while reading the K&R I got stuck at an example problem.

Here the aim of the program is to count the newlines, new words and the number of characters entered in the input.
The code given in the book is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

void main(){
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    nl=nw=nc=0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if(state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }  
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
    

}
```

It might look silly but sorry I'm  new to C. I learnt that if the 'if' statement's condition gets true, it simply doesn't check any other else if & else statements condition, it only executes its body and thus doesn't execute the bodies of other else & else if statements.

But, in the code above **(line:16)** after checking the input with conditions of non word (whitespace), it follows with an else if statement. And increments the nw in its body. But how can else if gets executed if the if statement's condition is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if(state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
```

the only way the code inside the braces is executed is:

- The condition in the first `if` is tested. That condition is `c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'`.
- If that condition is false, the `else` part is executed.
- The `else` contains an `if` statement, so the condition in the second `if` is tested. That condition is `state == OUT`.
- If that condition is true, the code inside the braces is executed.

So the code inside the braces is executed if `c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'` is false and `state == OUT` is true.

Answer (score 0):

This can be formulated in many ways; I prefer aligning the blocks more explicit:

```
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else 
            if (state == OUT) {
                state = IN;
                ++nw;
            }
```

The complicated part here is not language related. It is the checking for word boundaries with help of a state variable called...`state`. (Which is set to `OUT` first)

---

> after checking the input with conditions of **new word**,

conditions of **non-word character** (white space)

Comment: So whenever it encounters a new word condition(i.e \n, \t, ' ' ) it simply changes its state to OUT and when again it encounter a input which doesn't satisfy the new word conditions(i.e, a valid character input) it checks the previous OUT state and converts it into IN & increments the nw. Am I Right!

Comment: yes, starting with "OUT" it counts how many times the state gets changed to "IN". Two consecutive spaces are NOT two "new words".

Answer (score 0):

After making pretty much research I found this [article](http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/sec_1.5.4_word_counting.html) which confirmed my guess.

The actual thing happening here is, the initial state will be OUT. And whenever you get out of the word that is by satisfying the newline, blank or tab condition, your state will be set to OUT, by executing the second if statement. This actually doesn't make any sense unless your state is IN.

So when, in the future of the program's execution when you encounter a valid input (not a '\n', '\t' or ' '), the else if block gets executed, changing the state to IN and incrementing the nw value.

And this process goes on until the end of the program. The program's logic will work well because the input never ends with a whitespace.